# Istio Multi-Cluster Mesh Automatic Service Discovery

Tags: istio

I have a setup Istio Multi-cluster with Multi-Primary on different networks following the link:
https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/multi-primary_multi-network/

As per verification steps all seems fine. Also Step-by-step Diagnosis for multi-network looks fine
https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/multi-primary_multi-network/

But seems in the following scenario the automatic service discovery is not happening. Is it expected to happen automatically or I have to do something.

Scenario not working:
ServiceA deployed in Cluster1 (namespace sample) and ServiceB deployed in Cluster2 (namespace sample). Now when I am trying to call ServiceB from serviceA (like http://ServiceB.sample:8080) it's saying bad address. But when I create only the SVC of ServiceB on Cluster1 then it started working fine.

I have only found when the SVC is created in the cluster1 then only the service on cluster2 can be recognized in cluster1. I expected this service discovery to happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Istio multi-cluster setup does not create services of one cluster in another cluster, you have to configure the required DNS yourself. for example you can create kubernetes services or configure DNS names in coredns.

PS: It does not matter which ip value you give in DNS. istio-proxy will route it correctly when it sees the correct name. so you can easily test it like `curl http://1.2.3.4:8080 --header 'host: ServiceB.sample'`